# MySQL Concat query alternative

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I have database table :

```
+----+--------+-----------+
| id |  name  | know_from |
+----+--------+-----------+
|  1 | Andy   |           |
|  2 | Tony   | Andy      |
|  3 | Ben    | Andy      |
|  4 | Miller | Ben       |
|  5 | Bob    | Tony      |
|  6 | Scott  | Andy      |
+----+--------+-----------+
```

How to effectively query it and expecting the result as below :

```
+----+--------+-------+------------------+
| id |  name  | total |  reference_list  |
+----+--------+-------+------------------+
|  1 | Andy   |     3 | Tony, Ben, Scott |
|  2 | Tony   |     1 | Bob              |
|  3 | Ben    |     1 | Miller           |
|  4 | Miller |     0 |                  |
|  5 | Bob    |     0 |                  |
|  6 | Scott  |     0 |                  |
+----+--------+-------+------------------+
```

I have a solution using `GROUP_CONCAT( know_from SEPARATOR ',')` but the server is still using MySQL ver 5.1 which doesn't support this syntax. Any query alternative? Thanks in advance!

P.S.) Don't tell me to update the version as solution

Comment: You might want to post your whole query solution to make it clearer on where is the problem

Comment: As far as I can see, MySQL 5.1. [does](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19078-01/mysql/mysql-refman-5.1/functions.html#function_group-concat) support that syntax. Unless you include the comma. Then AFAIK **no** version supports it. i.e. `GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR ',')` should work, `GROUP_CONCAT(name, SEPARATOR ',')` can't possibly.

Comment: Thanks, I think 5.1 just doesn't work with SEPARATOR

Comment: Docs say it does. Then again, I can't test it - I'm certainly not going to install 5.1. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try concating the name string with the separator before the group concat

```
group_concat(concat(name,','))
```

And remove the last **,** from the resultant string.

Comment: Thanks, I use `GROUP_CONCAT(know_from)` instead without SEPARATOR

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
group_concat(`name` separator ',') as Name
```